# How to clone/pull a git repository, ignoring LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Is there a way to explicitly ignore all git-lfs files on `clone` and `pull`?
(besides uninstalling `git-lfs` which I ended up doing).

---

In this case git-lfs just contains pre-compiled libs for a platform I don't use... so there is absolutely no use in getting them.

Comment: Are they in a particular directory? You could try sparse checkout in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure, they seem to be scattered about, irrespective, if there were a way to opt-out it would be preferable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716509/fail-to-clone-repository-with-git-lfs/46656484#46656484 has required steps.

Comment: @ideasman42 could you accept an answer to this question?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Two alternatives:

(1) Using the GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE variable:

```
GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone SERVER-REPOSITORY
```

Obs: for "Windows", use the following two commands:

```
set GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1  
git clone SERVER-REPOSITORY
```

(2) Configuring the git-lfs smudge:

```
git config --global filter.lfs.smudge "git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f"
git config --global filter.lfs.process "git-lfs filter-process --skip"
    
git clone SERVER-REPOSITORY
```

To undo this configuration, execute:

```
git config --global filter.lfs.smudge "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config --global filter.lfs.process "git-lfs filter-process"
```

Comment: It would be good if this were possible without installing `git-lfs` at all. Currently this means if I want to make a source package, it needs to depend on `go`, `ruby` + some extras... adding up to over 220mb of deps, simply so I can tell it to be ignored :S

Comment: Actually it is. This is the alternative number 0, if you don't install git-lfs all lfs files will be just ignored.

Comment: Not on my test with https://github.com/opentoonz/opentoonz I get the errors: `git-lfs: command not found` `error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge -- %f' failed 127` `warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.`

Comment: Update, turns out I had once used git-lfs and it was left in by `.gitconfig`. So this can work, it's just not ideal if others are expected to build the package.

Comment: This still downloads all the LFS objects, so is okay but not ideal.

Comment: On windows, use 2 commands: `set GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1` `git clone SERVER-REPOSITORY`

Comment: The git config method (2) still raises a smudge error, only (1) GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE worked for me

Comment: Why do we need two git config functions?

Comment: I don't know, but it's needed the Filter Process (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-filter-process.1.ronn) and the Smudge (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-smudge.1.ronn).

Comment: @ideasman42: Could you elaborate what exactly what was left in your .gitconfig?

I just tried it out on Linux: Without git-lfs, the file was just not fetched, instead I had a small file with the hash etc. After installing git-lfs, it was fetched automatically.

But I don't see any change in my ~/.gitconfig ...

But actually, I do see a section [filter "lfs"] in my /etc/gitconfig, so maybe that solves the mystery.

Comment: this does not work at all! it maybe works on some peoples projects, but not on mine, maybe some little difference somewhere, looking forward to the next 3 hours of googling and trial n' error. this is classical git behavior all over again, I don't understand why they didn't just make this straight forward or usable, I guess usability is the mortal enemy in this scenario... this is quite literally the very first anybody using LFS is trying to figure out and it's like finding nemo

Comment: Worth noting that this also works great for pulling an existing repo with LFS, ignoring the LFS objects (such as in the case of reaching the LFS quota for the month). In that case running `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git pull` works perfectly. 

Seems that running `git lfs pull` after increasing the quota should likewise pull the missing LFS changes.

Answer (score 34):

I'm currently struggling myself to find a clean way to download (and remove afterwards) large files with git-lfs.

However, there is a third alternative to the post of @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira:

`git lfs install --skip-smudge`

will define globally to skip lfs downloads initially, when cloning repositories.

---

**EDIT:**
I've created a tutorial for basic git-lfs handling. Any feedback and suggestions are very welcome.

You can find it at:

https://sabicalija.github.io/git-lfs-intro/

or pull it via:

`git clone https://github.com/sabicalija/git-lfs-intro.git`

Comment: After such cloning can I add new big files to the cloned repo and push them?

Comment: Sure, you can add more files and push them to a new repository or to the current one - with sufficient access rights of course.

Comment: I received `git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` I had to `apt install git-lfs`.

Comment: feedback: for me the 'Setup git repository with git-lfs' part is visually to complex. the part 'Clone repository' is nice any simple.

Answer (score 0):

adding to the post of @Alija
you can `git lfs install` without `--skip-smudge` to return to normal git lfs to download large file.