# Disabling GIT LFS for GitLab CI

Tags: git, gitlab

How can configure the GitLab CI runners to clone without downloading the LFS files? Those files are not needed for the tests and it would speed up our development workflow significantly. Any help is very much appreciated!

I have only encountered the same question on reddit: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/8bi0kb/disable_lfs_downloading_for_ci/) with unfortunately no useful answers. Note that I also posed the question the gitlab forum two months ago ([link](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/disabling-git-lfs-for-gitlab-ci/16611)) with no luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried [setting the variablee `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone/pull a git repository, ignoring LFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019529/how-to-clone-pull-a-git-repository-ignoring-lfs)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, as its specific to GitLab CI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try setting the variable `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1`

```
variables:
  GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE: "1"
```

or take control over the `git checkout` call, and set `lfs.fetchexclude` beforehand

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
script:
  - git config lfs.fetchexclude "*"
  - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you! So I tried to set the variable and in principle, it works, but only with `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE: "1"`, with the proposed solution, Gitlab CI gives me the error `FATAL: invalid value for variable "GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE"`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have adjusted my post.

Comment: GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE: "1" worked big time for me.