How to prevent Git LFS files from being downloaded during clone?
How can I exclude Git LFS files from being pulled during a clone?
It seems that git lfs clone is deprecated, but there is no exclude option for git clone:
git lfs clone -X "*.*" MY_REPO
WARNING: `git lfs clone` is deprecated and will not be updated
          with new flags from `git clone`

`git clone` has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to `git lfs clone`.

git clone -X "*.*" MY_REPO
error: unknown switch `X'


Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42019529/2422776

A workaround is to run git lfs uninstall before git clone. And make sure the following lfs configuration options are gone from gitconfig. git config -l --show-origin | grep lfs should print none of them.
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process

If you want lfs files later,
git lfs install
git lfs fetch
git lfs checkout


I preferred the -X option to just exclude files rather than altering the local config or doing a global uninstall of lfs.
